# How to select text on Google Search, when using Chrome for iOS7?

Tags: google-chrome, ios

Once you type the text to be searched on the omnibox, it is replaced by a long URL, e.g. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20select%20text%20on%20google%20search%2c%20when%20using%20chrome%20for%20ios7%3f

Then, if you want to select some of the previous text, tap and hold will not work.

Is there other alternative?

Comment: I searched for iOS on the menu, I didn't notice this option. It makes sense.

Comment: IF you would prefer this question there I believe the proper procedure is for you to flag here and request a mod migrate this.

Comment: Shame though to lose you from here - you would seem to be a welcome addition!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "losing me"?

Comment: So far (you have not had much time) this has been your only activity here. If you like Ask Different you might not want to return here!

Comment: Ah! :-) Don't worry, I'll be around when able to contribute or to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can double tap to select a word, then just adjust the selection. More hints on this [link](http://lifehacker.com/five-shortcuts-for-faster-text-selection-in-ios-1641490708)